# Detect anchor is leading to an active window.location

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, comparison, href

Having such an html:

```
<a class="someclass" href="some/url/absolute/or/relative">Blah</a>
```

... along with such javascript:

```
$("a.someclass").onclick(function() {
    var link = $(this).attr("href");
    if (link == window.location) // <<<<<<<<<<<<
        doSomethingSpecial();
    else
        doOtherThing();
    return false;
});
```

this code obviously doesn't work.

**How to reliably detect that some anchor is leading to the current browser location?**

Here are some notes:

- Anchor's `href` could be either absolute or relative.
- the fragments of the URLs should be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `$('a').attr('href')` always returns the relative path. You need to use the native `obj.href` attribute to get the absolute path, strip hashes and then compare:

```
var clean = function(str) {
    return str.replace(/(\#.*)/,'').toLowerCase();
}

$("a.someclass").click(function(e) {
    if (clean(this.href) == clean(window.location)) {
        // the link destination is equal to window.location (excluding hashes)
        doSomethingSpecial();
    } else {
        doOtherThing();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to compare pathnames, you can grab it directly from the anchor element:

```
$("a.someclass").click(function(e) {
    if (this.pathname == window.location.pathnname) {
        doSomethingSpecial();
    } else {
        doOtherThing();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: @David: Are you absolutely sure that `$('a').attr('href')' always returns the relative path? It would be very good since I could compare to `location.pathname'. However, what about fragment?...

Comment: Some older browsers don't include the initial '/' on the anchor.pathname but they do on window.location.pathname. If you care about the older browsers then you need to check for it before doing the compare.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you cannot detect that. Because I can write onclick event handler and then write the code that leads to the current location itself. In this case you can't really depend n the href attribute.

```
function ReloadWin()
{
    window.location.reload();
}

<a href="#" onclick="ReloadWin();">Click me to reload</a>
```

Comment: You absolutely right about `onclick`, however i need to detect if anchor's `href` is leading to the current location.

Comment: This will also be difficult, since I can write the same event on `href` also.

Comment: doesn't matter for me. I know my anchors are generated with pure href.

Comment: +1 for pointing out that it is not possible to detect what I want in all circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a.someclass").click(function(){

        //convert both to lower case
        var h=$(this).attr("href").toLowerCase();
        var l=window.location.href.toLowerCase();

        //if has hash tag remove portion after if
        if(l.indexOf("?")>0)
            l=l.substring(0,l.indexOf("?"));
        if(l.indexOf("#")>0)
            l=l.substring(0,l.indexOf("#"));

        if(l.length > h.length)
            l = l.substring(l.length - h.length);

        if(l==h){
            alert("On same page");
        }else{
            alert("Other page");
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```